# Linear Programming Problem in Graphical Method.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I want to solve the following linear programming problem by graphical method :

$$\text{Minimize}\quad Z=0.4x_1+0.5x_2,$$
Subject to
$$0.3x_1+0.1x_2\le2.7$$
$$0.5x_1+0.5x_2=6$$
$$0.6x_1+0.4x_2\ge6$$
and,
$$x_1\ge0,x_2\ge0$$

The book which I am following also shows the graph :
[image]

But I am not understanding how did they draw the graph ? Say, for example, how did they draw the line for $0.3x_1+0.1x_2\le2.7$ and $0.5x_1+0.5x_2=6$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rearrange the equations into the form $x_2\leq mx_1+c$

Comment: If I rewrite $0.3x_1+0.1x_2\le2.7$, it becomes $x_1\le 9-(1/3)x_2$. What to do next ? How can I draw the line ?

Comment: Id suggest doing some quick background reading on graphing linear equations and inequalities.  http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/linear-inequality.php